# I have a question on some python code given in a python course

Tags: python, recursion

The code, from a course I am taking, is simple recursion but what I cannot understand is.... when the code is run how does `a` get added to `a`? The `print` statement at line 2 shows `a = 4` for every count yet when a is returned it is equal to `24`.

I've tried putting print statements at different locations to see why variable "a" is getting added to "a" but no luck. With three variables why does `a` only get added to `a`?

```
def mult(a,b,c):

   print ('a =',a, ' b =',b, ' c = ',c)
   print(' ')
   if b == 1:
       return a
   else:
      c += 1

return a + mult(a, b-1, c)

a=4
b=6
c=0
x=mult(a,b,c)
print("a*b = ",x)
```

The code runs correctly but not sure why.

Comment: This recurses exactly `b times`. This means the result is `a * b = 4 * 6 = 24`

Answer (score 1):

It only returns `a` when `b == 1`. When `b == 2`, it returns `a + mult(a, 1, c) == a + a`. When `b == 3`, it returns `a + mult(a, 2, c) == a + (a + a)`, etc.

(Note that `c` doesn't affect the return value at all; its only purpose is to count how deep the recursion gets. You should notice that the value of `b + c` remains constant throughout the process; every time you add 1 to `c`, you subtract `1` from `b`.)

Answer (score 1):

As written, you're not using `c`, so you can rewrite it as:

```
def mult(a,b):

    print('a =',a, ' b =',b)
    print()
    if b == 1:
        return a
    else:
        return a + mult(a, b-1)

a=4

b=6

x=mult(a,b)

print("a*b = ",x)
```

The best thing to do is expand what is happening by hand.  In this case,
mult() is being called repeatedly.  So with a=4 and b=6, expanding the
calls, you'd end up with:

```
mult(4, 6) => 4 + mult(4, 5)
           => 4 + 4 + mult(4, 4)
           => 4 + 4 + 4 + mult(4, 3)
           => 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + mult(4, 2)
           => 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + mult(4, 1)
           => 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4
           => 24
```

Comment: So what you're saying is "a" isn't being added to the mult(a,b,c) variables. Is it similar to when you concatenate a character to a string in this but in this case         a + a + etc....? Until b == 1 then the entire addition is returned as "a"?

Comment: @radpad79 Not quite.  With recursion, algorithms keep recursing until you hit the terminating condition (b == 1 in this case).  In the mean time, there is data stored on the stack.  Remember, it was trying to compute `a + mult(...)`.  It needs to finish that computation.  So what actually happens is the `a` is returned for `mult(4, 1)` in the b == 1 case, which allows ` 4 + mult(4, 1)` to be computed, which is the answer to `mult(4, 2)`, and it keeps unrolling until you return from the `mult(4, 6)` call.  So it completes kind of bottom up.

Comment: Got it, I haven't read about data getting stored on a stack during algorithms. The instructor put that code out without really covering it during the session. Thanks for the help, it finally makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, this function never changes `a`. However, it returns `a + mult(a, b-1, c)`, and that's exactly where `a` is added to `a` (the return value of `mult(a, 2, c)`), so there's no wonder it may return something different from `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems like correct behavior. Let me demonstrate your example but with smaller numbers.

```
a=2
b=2
c=0
```

First iteration: b is not 1 so returm mult(2, 1, 1)

Second iteration: b is 1 so return a (return 2)

Now we step back to previous stack and we need to return a which is 2 + result of mult(2,1,1) which is also 4 and we get 8.

Try applying this logic to your example and you will see that it actually makes perfect sense to a always be 4 and finally return 24.

Answer (score 0):

In every recursion, the `mult(a, b-1, c)` isn't being added, it is being called, and then it is called again...

Up until the point where `b == 1`, then it will return only `a`.

Basically, the first time `mult` runs, it will call:

```
mult(4, 6 - 1, 1)
```

and when this is being run, it will call:

```
mult(4, 5 - 1, 2)
```

and when this is being run, it will call:

```
mult(4, 4 - 1, 3)
```

and when this is being run, it will call:

```
mult(4, 3 - 1, 4)
```

and when this is being run, it will call:

```
mult(4, 2 - 1, 5)
```

and, finally, when this is being run, `b` will finally be equal to `1` and return `a`.

So, `mult(4, 2 - 1, 5)` returns `a`.

Then `mult(4, 3 - 1, 4)` returns `a + (a)`

Then `mult(4, 4 - 1, 3)` returns `a + (a + (a))`

Then `mult(4, 5 - 1, 2)` returns `a + (a + (a + (a)))`

Then `mult(4, 6 - 1, 1)` returns `a + (a + (a + (a + (a))))`

And finally, the originally called `mult(4, 6, 0)` will be run returning `a + (a + (a + (a + (a + (a)))))`

Which basically means 6 times a, which is equal to 24. But the value of `a` was never changed.